# Is there a way to swipe out of React-Native-Swiper component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-swiper

I am using react-native-swiper as part of my On-Boarding screens, and once the user swipes through the 3 welcome screens, I want them to be able to swipe once more and the next screen they see will be the main feed screen on which they cannot swipe back.